# React-js MUI Tooltip disappears on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

The default behavior for the MUI Tooltip is as follows:

1. When the button/icon to open a tooltip is NOT on focus, the tooltip will NOT disappear by clicking directly on the popper.
2. When the button/icon to open a tooltip IS focused, the tooltip WILL disappear by clicking directly on the popper.

I want the tooltip to NOT disappear when the popper is clicked on, even when the button/icon for it IS focused. I am unable to identify what is causing this behavior. Does anybody have any ideas?

I've tried using leaveDelay but it feels like a clunky patch rather than addressing the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `disableFocusListener` property. It disables `focus-visible` related functionality though, so should not be considered as an overall solution, but it helped when I faced the same issue.